# Why do i get binary output using curl

Tags: curl, binary

Not sure if it is ok to share the website I tried to get its source, but I think it is necessary for a better explanation. And I apologize if it's not in advance

The command:
`curl -k -L -s https://www.mi.com`

The output was binary data for some reason by getting the following error

```
Warning: Binary output can mess up your terminal. Use "--output -" to tell
Warning: curl to output it to your terminal anyway, or consider "--output
Warning: <FILE>" to save to a file.
```

How can I read the page  HTML source? thanks!

Answer (score 69, accepted):

The returned data is **compressed**, you can instruct `curl` to handle the decompression directly by adding the [`--compressed`](https://curl.se/docs/manpage.html#--compressed) option:

```bsh
curl -k -L -s --compressed https://www.mi.com
```

Comment: We noticed when going through a CDN(Akamai/Cloudflare),etc requests are compressed by default

Answer (score 11):

Just redirect it to a file, then you can investigate what it is:

```
curl -k -L -s https://www.mi.com > outFile
```

You can now use the `file` command to see what `outFile` contains:

```
$ file outFile 
outFile: gzip compressed data, from Unix, original size modulo 2^32 135402
```

So, you just downloaded compressed data. To see it, either decompress:

```
mv outFile outFile.gz ## gzip requires the .gz extension
gunzip outFile.gz
```

Or just use a tool that can handle compressed data such as `zmore`:

```
zmore outFile
```

Or `zcat`:

```
zcat outFile
```

Comment: I tired this, and `file` told me: `gzip compressed data, from Unix, original size modulo 2^32 114078`. Then I tried `gunzip` and got errors: `invalid compressed data--crc and data--length errors`. But `zmore` showed at least part of the data. Strange.

Comment: @LuisA.Florit sounds like an incomplete download.

Answer (score 4):

`Use "--output -" to tell Warning: curl to output it to your terminal anyway`

like in

```
curl -k -L --output - s https://www.mi.com
```

or `--output file` to save it to a file like in

```
curl -k -L --output filename s https://www.mi.com
```

and examine the file with your favourite editor.

Answer (score 1):

If you don't know what format the [*binary output*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binary_file) has it would be safer to **inspect the output format** first.

Otherwise as you already use `-s`, for silent mode like in batch/automation scripts, you could **directly pipe it on** to a suitable binary-converter.

Or, assuming the HTTP output was compressed, simply **decompress it**.

#### Inspecting binary curl output

1. Use [`-I`](https://curl.se/docs/manpage.html#-i) to see response-headers only and view `Content-` headers for a given [*media type*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Media_type) (also known as **MIME type**) indicating the (binary) format:

```bsh
curl -k -L -s https://www.mi.com -I
```

E.g. `curl -k -L -s https://www.mi.com -I | grep Content-` will also show other output-metadata like encoding (e.g. UTF-8), length in bytes (here 169747 bytes, after redirection):

> Content-Type: text/html
>
> Content-Length: 223
>
> Content-Type: **text/html**; charset=utf-8
>
> Content-Length: 169747

Note: above HTTP request was redirected, thus we get 2 responses and 2 response-headers from curl. The first is from redirection, the second from final output.

2. Pipe to `type` to inspect the binary data type (file-type):

```bsh
curl -k -L -s https://www.mi.com | type
```

3. Using [`-o` or `--output`](https://curl.se/docs/manpage.html#-o) to save to a file:

```bsh
curl -k -L -s https://www.mi.com -o outFile
```

Same like [redirection  `> outFile` suggested by terdon](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/638225/384422).

#### Passing binary output on (e.g. to an image-viewer)

You can also use the pipe to pass e.g. an image indicated by response-header `Content-Type: image/x-icon` to a stdin-accepting viewer like `feh` to show it:

```bsh
curl -k -L -s https://www.mi.com/favicon.ico | feh
```

#### De-compressing curl output

Binary output may be the result of [*HTTP compression*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HTTP_compression) which is often used to save bandwidth and speed-up transmission.

1. Piping to [`zcat`](https://explainshell.com/explain/1/zcat) to view unzipped directly:

```bsh
curl -k -L -s https://www.mi.com | zcat
```

If curl's output was not zipped as expected following warning will show:

> gzip: stdin: not in gzip format

As [terdon explained interactively](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/638225/384422).

2. Using [`--compressed`](https://curl.se/docs/manpage.html#--compressed):

```bsh
curl -k -L -s https://www.mi.com --compressed
```

As [Stephen already answered](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/638228/384422).